# jQuery draggable text from input to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to allow text in form input to be moved from one input to another via dragging the text instead of copy/paste. Anybody has a thought on how to accomplish this?

Comment: by default it is there for textboxes. You can drag selected input to text box.

Comment: You can try something like this  $("#txt1").draggable({
       containment: "document"
   });
   $("#txt2").droppable({
       accept: "#txt1"
   });